# Is rpm the only file extension for repositories

Tags: centos, rhel, rpm, package-management, repository

I've noticed that repositories in CentOS have the .rpm extension.

- Are there other extensions?
- Is .rpm specific to the operating system? i.e. do other linux operating systems have other extensions?

Comment: `.rpm` is specific to the package manager software, which Red Hat uses, CentOS and other have inherited. Others are free to use it as well, but many other Linux distros use other package managers.

Comment: Historically, RPM stood for RedHat Package Manager, but most people have forgotten that and think it's Repository Package Manager or something similar.

Comment: The extension does not matter. It matters what `file` says about that file. You could name any `rpm` `exe` instead. See below for pbm`s answer that contains all details.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[RPM file](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RPM_Package_Manager) is not repository. It is type of package that is used in CentOS (and Red Hat and some other distributions). [Repository](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_repository) is place that packages are kept and can be downloaded and installed by [package manager](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Package_management_system) in your distribution.

Another package format is [DEB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deb_%28file_format%29). It is used by Debian, Ubuntu and their derivatives.

There are also [other formats](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_package_formats), but that two are most common.

Comment: Another common distribution that uses `rpm` is SuSE.